# need help with this query

Tags: mysql

This will be in MySQL. Table consists of following fields:

```
Date, ID, blah, blahblah, blahblahblah
```

I believe the primary key needs to be Date & ID.

The query I want to run is for every `Date`, count all the `IDs` but only if this is the last date the ID shows up.

So if the ID shows up in the database on 9/9/16 but NOT on 9/10/16 then we would say that it disappeared and therefore add it to the total count for date 9/9/16.

If that same ID later reappears on 9/11/16, when we run the query again that ID will no longer be added to the count as of 9/9/16.  If on 9/12/16 that ID disappears again then it would be added to the count as of 9/11/16.

Here's some sample data.  I did not put any data in for the "blahs" since it is not relevant for the query (I believe):

```
Date,   ID, blah,   blahblah,   blahblahblah
9/8/2016,   1           
9/8/2016,   2           
9/8/2016,   3           
9/8/2016,   4           
9/8/2016,   5           
9/8/2016,   6           
9/8/2016,   7           
9/8/2016,   8           
9/9/2016,   1           
9/9/2016,   2           
9/9/2016,   3           
9/9/2016,   4           
9/9/2016,   5           
9/9/2016,   9           
9/9/2016,   10          
9/9/2016,   11          
9/10/2016,  2           
9/10/2016,  4           
9/10/2016,  6           
9/10/2016,  11          
9/10/2016,  12          
9/10/2016,  13
```

The expected output run on 9/9/16 would be:

```
Date, Total IDs Last Day
9/8/16,3
9/9/16,8
```

The expected output run on 9/10/16 would be:

```
Date, Total IDs Last Day
9/8/16,2
9/9/16,4
9/10/16,6
```

Note that when the query is run on 9/10/16, the total for 9/8/16 is different from when it was run on 9/9/16 because an ID (number 6) disappeared but then re-appeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use a `not exists` to filter out any rows that appear for a later date.

```
select date, count(*)
  from your_table a
 where not exists( select 1
                     from your_table b
                    where a.id = b.id
                      and b.date > a.date )
 group by date
```